# angular v1.2.1 - ng-repeat updating function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat as such which is working wonderfully.
the function `getResultRows()` is out of my control and I don't have true access to the scope. I've noticed when the data behind `getResultRows()` changes the dirty checking on the `ng-repeat` doesn't fire. Any ideas how to get around this in **angularjs v1.2.1**?

```
 <li ng-repeat="row in getResultRows()">
```

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: When you say you don't have access to the scope, do you mean the scope that getResultsRows belongs to?  Sounds to me like getResultsRow is not running $scope.$apply().

Comment: In the sense of there is a lot of legacy code in getResultsRows which I'd ideally not go near for fear of regressions etc.

Comment: If you can't change the code, then how do you propose to change the code? I don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **track by**. "You can also provide an optional tracking function which can be used to associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. If no tracking function is specified the ng-repeat associates elements by identity in the collection."

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat